# breaking apart a monolithic one project .net solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have to work on an web application where everything is crammed into one project. The things, that should be their own projects reside in different namespaces. I would like to separate them into different projects within the solution.

Is there a way to do automate this process or do I have to do everything by hand?

Comment: ReSharper would help make this a far less painful process.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do it by hand, because there is no reliable way in which a computer could determine which files should go into a project together.